# Checking solution of $\frac1x \frac{∂}{∂x}[x\frac{∂f(x,y)}{∂x}]+\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{∂^2f(x,y)}{∂y^2}-c^2f(x,y)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here's what I did:

Separating variables $$f(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$$
$$\frac1x \frac{∂}{∂x}[x\frac{∂XY}{∂x}]+\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{∂^2XY}{∂y^2}-c^2XY=0$$
$$\frac{Y}x \frac{d}{dx}[x\frac{dX}{dx}]+\frac{X}{x^2}\frac{d^2Y}{dy^2}-c^2XY=0$$
$$\frac{1}{Xx} \frac{∂}{∂x}[x\frac{dX}{dx}]+\frac{1}{Yx^2}\frac{d^2Y}{dy^2}-c^2=0$$
$$\frac{x}{X} \frac{∂}{∂x}[x\frac{dX}{dx}]+\frac{1}{Y}\frac{d^2Y}{dy^2}-x^2c^2=0$$

Which lead to two ordinary eqs.

- $\frac{x}X\frac{d}{dx}[x\frac{dX}{dx}]-(x^2c^2 + k^2)X=0$
- $\frac{1}{Y}\frac{d^2Y}{dy^2}=-k$

I'm not sure about these partial results and how to find X(x) and Y(y). I'd appreciate if anyone could help me out.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that middle partial derivative is the first partial and not $$\frac1{x^2}\frac{\partial^2f(x,y)}{\partial y^2}$$ That would be Schroedinger's equation for constant potential in $2$ dimensions in polar coordinates. Also you need a separation constant for your two ordinary equations. The first should equal $\lambda$, not $0$, and the second should equal $-\lambda$. Oh yes, and you dropped a factor of $x$ in the $x$ equation.

Comment: @user5713492 you're right. I missed that one. I'll correct now.

Comment: You have two equations $\frac1X\frac{d}{dx}[x\frac{dX}{dx}]-x^2c^2=k$
and $\frac{1}{Y}\frac{d^2Y}{dy^2}=-k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{C}$.  It is not necessary that $k=0$.  The first equation becomes $x X''(x)+X'(x)-(x^2c^2+k)X(x)=0$, whereas the second one gives $Y''(y)+kY(y)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $y$ is the azimuthal coordinate, the first equation to be addressed is
$$\frac{d^2Y}{dy^2}+kY=0$$
If $k<0$, then the solution is
$$Y=c_1e^{\sqrt{-k}y}+c_2e^{-\sqrt{-k}y}$$
No boundary conditions are given, so let us assume that the $y$ coordinate is periodic with period $2\pi$. Then $Y(y)$ ought to have a continuous first derivative, because you took its second derivative. So we have
$$Y(0)=c_1+c_2=Y(2\pi)=c_1e^{2\sqrt{-k}\pi}+c_2e^{-2\sqrt{-k}\pi}$$
and
$$Y^{\prime}(0)=c_1\sqrt{-k}-c_2\sqrt{-k}=Y^{\prime}(2\pi)=c_1\sqrt{-k}e^{2\sqrt{-k}\pi}-c_2\sqrt{-k}e^{-2\sqrt{-k}\pi}$$
Dividing the second equation by $\sqrt{-k}$ and adding to the first, we get
$$2c_1=2c_1e^{2\sqrt{-k}\pi}$$
Which implies $c_1=0$ and so it follows that $c_2=0$. If $k=0$, then
$$Y=c_1+c_2y$$
Periodicity requires
$$c_1=c_1+2\pi c_2$$
So that $c_2=0$ but then $Y^{\prime}(y)=0$, so we do have a solution $Y_0(y)=1$. If $k>0$, then the general solution is
$$Y=c_1\cos\sqrt ky+c_2\sin\sqrt ky$$
Periodicity requires
$$c_1=c_1\cos2\sqrt k\pi+c_2\sin2\sqrt ky$$
$$c_2\sqrt k=-c_1\sqrt k\sin2\sqrt k\pi+c_2\sqrt k\cos2\sqrt k\pi$$
To get a nontrivial solution we need the determinant of the coefficients to vanish
$$\det\begin{bmatrix}\cos2\sqrt k\pi-1&\sin2\sqrt k\pi\\
-\sqrt k\sin2\sqrt k\pi&\sqrt k(\cos2\sqrt k\pi-1)\end{bmatrix}=2\sqrt k(1-\cos2\sqrt k\pi)=0$$
So $k=n^2$ for some positive integer $n$. Thus the solutions to the azimuthal equation are $Y_0(y)=1$ and $Y_n(y)=a_n\cos y+b_n\sin y$. Now the radial equation becomes
$$x^2\frac{d^2X}{dx^2}+x\frac{dX}{dx}-(c^2x^2+n^2)X=0$$
(Note that this equation is still incorrect in the original question.) This is Bessel's differential equation of imaginary argument and the solutions are $X_n(x)=c_nI_n(cx)+d_nK_n(cx)$. Normally you have some sort of boundary condition at this point such as $X_n(0)$ is finite, in which case $d_n=0$ or $X_n(x)$ remains finite as $x\rightarrow\infty$, in which case $c_n=0$.

Comment: That really helped. Thank you. I've just changed the original question.

Comment: But then you should change the $\frac xX$ to simply $x$ in your final expression for the radial equation. Getting used to proofreading MathJax takes a little time, but ultimately you can work an order of magnitude or so faster than with Microsoft's equation editor.